# C++/OpenSSL load PEM into STACK_OF(X509)

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm loading a `PEM` in a `BIO` (from a file OR from user input directly).
This PEM can contain 1 to N certificates stacked.

I can't find a function that give me a `STACK_OF(X509*)` from my bio, like `PEM_read_bio_X509` does for a single `X509*`.

Does such a function exist ? If it doesn't , could i get the same result in another way ?

Comment: Does this help: http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certstack.htm

Comment: Yes thanks , i had already found this link but didn't dug enough in it.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Reinier Torenbeek the link is outdated, it's now [here](http://www.fm4dd.com/openssl/certstack.shtm).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant part from the [link](http://www.fm4dd.com/openssl/certstack.shtm) @Reinier Torenbeek provided:

```c
STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *certstack;
const char ca_filestr[] = "./cabundle.pem";

stackbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
outbio   = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
 * Load the file with the list of certificates in PEM format  *
 * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (BIO_read_filename(stackbio, ca_filestr) <= 0) {
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error loading cert bundle into memory\n");
    exit(-1);
}

certstack = PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(stackbio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```